# Php array search not working

Tags: php, arrays, search

Hi really need help here is my function.

```
function isdAuthorTrue( $post_id ) { 


    $coauthors = get_post_meta( $post_id, "coAuthors" );

    print_r($coauthors);
    // print_r output Array ( [0] => 78 )

     $key = array_search( 78, $coauthors );
     $key = 0;
     if($key !== false) {

       return true;

     } else {

         return false;
          }
}
```

then i am trying to do and if statement around it that isnt working.

```
$test = isdAuthorTrue( 102 );

echo $test;

if($test){

    echo "yes";

}else{

    echo "no";
}
```

i keep getting no what am i doing wrong???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting "no" because array_search returns the key, in this case, `0`. PHP evaluates that as `false`. Edit: didn't notice the strict comparison -- no it doesn't.

Also, you're explicitly setting `$key` to `0`...

Comment: Uh no, user is using `===` not `==` (with magic type conversion)  `0!==false`, `0==false`

Comment: Not the case, he's using `!==` not `!=` so types will be checked too.  `0 == false` will return `true`, `0 === false` will not.

Answer (score 1):

As @marc points out, you can just use in_array... and simplify the whole function down to one line:

```
function isdAuthorTrue($post_id,$authorid=78) { 
    return in_array($authorid,get_post_meta( $post_id, "coAuthors"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array serach returns the key of the needle that is 0 that is false. You should do.

```
if($test !== false){

    echo "yes";

}else{

    echo "no";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set `$key = 0`? `$key` is the index. So it is never `FALSE`.
Why not use `in_array($needle, $haystack)`?